# link in table does not trigger onclick function when clicked the 2nd time around

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have a html table which has a span that looks like the ff:

```
<TD class=pageinfo style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">
    <SPAN class=paginate_pageinfo>
        <SPAN class=paginate_pagelinks style="PADDING-TOP: 5px">
            <SPAN class=paginate_link_enabled>1</SPAN>
        </SPAN>
    </SPAN>
</TD>
```

the span has an `onclick function` that looks like this:

```
$("#tblResponsesList").find("span.paginate_link_enabled").click(function (event) {
    timer = setTimeout('setColors()', 250);
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
});
```

If I click the **span** the first time, it triggers the `onclick function`. But when I click the span again, it doesnt trigger the `onclick function` **anymore**.

I have no idea why

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue

Comment: Can you attach a fiddle/codepen? And setTimeout is wrong, it has to be setTimeout(setColor, 250);